# AngularJS - watchCollection triggering events

Tags: angularjs

According to the angular's [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24watchCollection), `watchCollection` watches properties of an object and executes whenever any of their values changes.

Here is a piece of code:

```
$scope.$watchCollection('obj', function () {
    if ($scope.obj.A == null) 
        $scope.obj.B = null;

    if ($scope.obj.B == null)
        $scope.obj.C = null;

    if ($scope.obj.C == null) 
        $scope.obj.D = null;
})
```

As you probably can notice the purpose of this function is to cascade `null` values whenever one of the properties is nullified. `$scope.obj` properties are being changed from a DOM bound input, and successfully firing the function.

What happens during execution, however, is that the function fires twice (should be thrice) when `$scope.obj.A` value changes to `null`. This is quite odd, considering `B` and `C` should be both nullified and therefore trigger the function again and again.

Any ideas about this?

---

**Update:** Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z3484/) to better explain this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "nullification" happens in one pass (one function call): Since you don't return after setting each property, once an `if` condition evaluates to true, all subsequest `if` conditions evaluate to true as well.

Thus, the first execution is due to `A`'s changing to `null` and the second execution is due to all the rest properties' changing to `null`.

---

If you want to see the "staggering" effect you expect, you need to add a return statements in each `if` block:

```
// We don't only need to check if something is `null`,
// but also if it changed from the last iteration,
// so we must keep a reference to the old values.
var oldObj = angular.copy($scope.obj, {});
$scope.$watchCollection('obj', function (newObj) {
    if ((newObj.A !== oldObj.A) && (newObj.A === null)) {
        oldObj.A = null;
        newObj.B = null;
        return;
    } else {
        oldObj.A = newObj.A;
    }

    if ((newObj.B !== oldObj.B) && (newObj.B === null)) {
        oldObj.B = null;
        newObj.C = null;
        return;
    } else {
        oldObj.B = newObj.B;
    }

    if ((newObj.C !== oldObj.C) && (newObj.C === null)) {
        oldObj.C = null;
        newObj.D = null;
        return;
    } else {
        oldObj.C = newObj.C;
    }
});
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/jAd5Y/)**.

Comment: I have tried your approach, somehow `B`, `D`, and `C` values are not changing to `null`. Perhaps a fiddle would explain this better, I'm gonna post one.

Comment: Updated question with a fiddle. Change `A`, `B`, `C`, then `D` dropdowns (in that order), then change `A` back to "Change Me" (the null value), see what happens.

Comment: Obviously :) Once `A` is `null` it will always enter the 1st `if` and return, before reaching the others. See the updated answer. Of cource, there is no practical reason to implement something like this (or is it).

Comment: Ok, while this does work, I don't understand why removing `(newObj.var !== oldObj.var)` condition wouldn't achieve the same behavior - it is more restrictive, so in a sense `if (newObj.A === null)` should cover it. We are getting back to basic programming here aren't we :]

Comment: The use case is four models where each model is related to the previous model (a hierarchy), so when `A` is reset `B`, `C`, and `D` no longer have any meaningful values and should be reset. Think of `Country`, `State`, `City`, etc.

Comment: @abstractpaper: Yes, that's fine to reset all related values, when `A` changes to null. What I mean is that there is no reason to not `nullify` them in one pass. So, all that `oldObj` stuff and the `return` statements should go away.

Comment: @abstractpaper: BTW, feel free to also upvote the answer if you really liked it :)

Comment: You said it, if I really liked it. Your answer is a correct answer hence the correct answer mark, but there should be a cleaner one; can you provide an example of what you just mentioned?

Comment: @abstractpaper: I provided you with this ugly, fun experiment, because you asked that the function should be called multiple times. You original version already does what you want. As I already mentioned, there is no reason for you to want your function to be called 4 times if it can "nullify" all values in one call. Take a look at **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/Z3484/1/)**.

Comment: @abstractpaper: Basically, the real answer is near the top, above the horizontal divider. I explain that it "nullifies" all properties and why it is called 2 times (and not more as you expected). Below the horizontal line is just fun (because I thought you wantd a version that "nullifies" each property in a separate iteration).

Comment: Perhaps I didn't direct the question correctly, all I wanted is to get the end result regardless of recalling the function. I wasn't achieving what I wanted to do, but now looking at your fiddle, it works! It looks like my problem is out of the scope of this question. Upvote well deserved. :)